# How to check if a SSH Private Key has a passphrase programmitically with C# on Windows 10

Tags: ssh, .net, passphrase

I already know there are a couple of similar questions but there is a pattern in the replies that the answers assume that this check is being done on a Linux or similar system. This means they refer to  ssh-keygen as a solution. This isn't viable in this instance.

The client program I'm developing needs to accept a private key file reference and then prompt the user for the passphrase if it is needed. This program is being written in C# under Windows 10. The language and OS are not optional. The library being used for SSH authentication is Renci.SSH (also not optional). All I can do is stream the text file in and parse it.
Other answers (and the example I just created with PuTTY Gen) suggest that the file will contain in the header the following:
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED

But further reading suggests that this not a reliable test. This is where I'm reading:
[How to check if an SSH private key has passphrase or not?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/how-to-check-if-an-ssh-private-key-has-passphrase-or-not)
In my use context Jakuje's answer (ssh-keygen -yf ) is not an acceptable solution.

Clearly I need the actual algorithm used by ssh-keygen with the -yf setting. Does anyone know where I can find this? Or can present it here in a way that is independent of programming language?

Comment: For the record I'm going to go with the simple header solution at this time unless I'm given a bettor solution. My team is using Putty Gen for creating their key pairs and this means I have a known situation. The intent of my question is to hopefully expand my application to a larger user base.

Comment: Thanks to whoever migrated this question, but I'm puzzled why it got moved as it relates to a software/network security issue.

Comment: 'Actual algorithm': For 'old' format OpenSSH calls (the libcrypto part of) OpenSSL specifically `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` which can do many things but in this case just looks at the `Proc-type` and `DEK-info` header lines. For 'new' format, see `sshkey_parse_private2` in [sshkey.c (open source)](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshkey.c).